# Use Table Alias as Column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
select a,b, (a+b) as c, (a-b) as d, (a+b)*-1 as e, (a+b)/(a-b) as f from test;
```

Is there a way where I can use my previously defined alias as column so it will be like:

`(a+b)/(a-b) as f from test` **to** `c/d as f from test`

Or any other solution where I will not re-code any of the expression in this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

```
SELECT a,b, 
    @c := (a+b) as c, 
    @d := (a-b) as d, 
    @c*-1 as e, 
    @c/@d as f
FROM test;
```

Comment: better answer, no need for subquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from (
 select a,b, (a+b) as c, (a-b) as d, (a+b)*-1 as e, (a+b)/(a-b) as f 
 from test
) s
```

Comment: can this expression **(a+b)/(a-b)** reuse **(a+b) as c and (a-b) as d** ? so will be like **c/d as f**?

Comment: yes, the inline view will retrieve columns: a, b, c, d, e, f and these can be used in any further calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Their can be many ways, but as per i know, you can do this by using subquery like this. 
you will get all your alias as column when you make main query as subquery and use it as per your requirement.

Check this tutorial for more stuff : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f form 
 (select a,b, (a+b) as c, (a-b) as d, (a+b)*-1 as e, (a+b)/(a-b) as f from test)
x;
```